Not able to import .pfx file to azure keyvault
I need to upload .pfx file to azure keyvault for using it in azure app gateway ssl purpose. When i upload the same .pfx file manually through UI i am able to upload. But for automation purpose i need this file to be fetched from key vault and hence i am trying to import it to azure keyvault but facing below error .
az keyvault certificate import --vault-name test -n test-vault -f test.pfx


(BadParameter) The specified PKCS#12 X.509 certificate content can not
be read. Please check if certificate is in valid PKCS#12 format. Code:
BadParameter Message: The specified PKCS#12 X.509 certificate content
can not be read. Please check if certificate is in valid PKCS#12
format.

Command used to create pfx file
openssl pkcs12 -export -out test.pfx -inkey test.key -in test.crt


You want to automate this using CLI or Powershell?

will automate it using terraform . Already app gateway is created using terraform , only i need to automate ssl configuration part

The .pfx file may not be in the correct format expected by Azure Key Vault. Azure Key Vault expects the .pfx file to be a valid PKCS#12 forma, Can you verify the .pfx file content, you can use the following command: openssl pkcs12 -in test.pfx -info If the .pfx file is not in the correct format, you can recreate it using the following command: openssl pkcs12 -export -out test.pfx -inkey test.key -in test.crt,

I have tested this in my environment, and it was successfully uploaded to Key Vault. Here is the result from the portal: Portal Result.

Please Check below solution.

i ran openssl pkcs12 -in test.pfx -info and it shows proper output having two keys

Can you paste the screenshot and edit the question? The one of the key are private key and another one is Public Key

I wont be able to share screenshot of openssl pkcs12 -in test.pfx -info due to policies. But i have ran same cmd which you have provided. Maybe .key or crt file should be in some other format ?

Can you please let me know should I convert. Cer file to pem ? Can you share the commands for pem format with base 64 ? Will be helpful

To convert .cer to .pem, Refer this Server Fault thread

Note that PKCS#12 is a container format that allows different encryption shemes for protecting the private key data. Most common is the old 3DES encryption scheme. The newer AES based encryption scheme is often not supported by PKCS#12 capable tools. Use an ASN.1 viewer to check which encryption scheme is used in your file.

@HarshadSolanki Any update on issue?


(BadParameter) The specified PKCS#12 X.509 certificate content can not be read. Please check if certificate is in valid PKCS#12 format. Code: BadParameter Message: The specified PKCS#12 X.509 certificate content can not be read. Please check if certificate is in valid PKCS#12 format.

The error message indicates that The .pfx file may not be in the correct format expected by Azure Key Vault.
Azure Key Vault expects the .pfx file to be a valid PKCS#12 format.
To verify the .pfx file content, you can use the following command:
openssl pkcs12 -in test.pfx -info
If the .pfx file is not in the correct format, you can recreate it using the following command:
openssl pkcs12 -export -out test.pfx -inkey test.key -in test.crt

I have tested this in my environment, and it was uploaded Successfully to Key Vault:

I've verified from Portal, here is the result from the portal:


